# Apache rewrite rule - regex help

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have 7 urls:

```
url: /v/3b89441db7986135e5eb9e1debf0cc23
url: /v/3b89441db7986135e5eb9e1debf0cc23/login
url: /v/3b89441db7986135e5eb9e1debf0cc23/logout
url: /v/3b89441db7986135e5eb9e1debf0cc23/access
url: /v/3b89441db7986135e5eb9e1debf0cc23/delete-attendee/:id
url: /v/3b89441db7986135e5eb9e1debf0cc23/edit-attendee/:id
url: /v/3b89441db7986135e5eb9e1debf0cc23/finalise
```

How could I write a rewrite rule that if these URLS are not matched, I redirect the user to another domain?

For example the part after /v/ is always a 32 character MD5 string. the :id part is always a number.

If you could give me a regex (regex has alas never been my forte) example for

```
/v/3b89441db7986135e5eb9e1debf0cc23
```

and

```
/v/3b89441db7986135e5eb9e1debf0cc23/edit-attendee/:id
```

that would be excellent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This regex matches your urls:

```
/v/[a-f0-9]{32}(/[a-z-]+(/\d+)?)?
```

In english...

- `/v/` is a literal
- `[a-f0-9]{32}` means 32 hex digits
- /[a-z-]+(/\d+)? means "/" then at least 1 of (any lowercase letter or a dash) then "/" then some digits
- surrounding a regex in `(...)?` means either one or none of them

FYI, this regex matches *all* urls given in question reasonably tightly

If you want to *not* match, use this:

```
^(?!/v/[a-f0-9]{32}(/[a-z-]+(/\d+)?)?$)
```

Comment: Hm, I guess Bohemian gave a regex matching the two latter requested strings. That the original poster wants to redirect a visitor via a rewrite rule if the string is different was not part of the requested solution. This part will be solved by original poster himself ;-)

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

`\/v\/[a-f0-9]{32}(\/(login|logout|access|delete-attendee\/:\d+|edit-attendee\/:\d+|finalise)?`

This will only match your accepted urls. You should adjust for your flavor or regex and appropriate escape chars.

Comment: But the `.{32}`part matches 32 characters and the request constrained it to md5 (lowercase), i.e.  `[a-f0-9]{32}` as given in Bohemians answer.

Comment: My mistake, I didn't check the format of md5 before posting. I've edited it to correct.

Answer (score 1):

You said that you want to redirect if URLs do not match, so first you must make a rule that matches all valid URLs, then prepend `!` to negate the match.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule !^v/[0-9a-f]{32}(/(login|logout|access|delete-attendee/\d+|edit-attendee/\d+|finalise))?$ http://your-other-domain/ [R]
```

The above rule should be placed in the `.htaccess` file present in the root directory of your website.

Comment: Hey @salman, thank you for your help. I removed the \: however it redirects for every URL given to it....

Comment: @Jamie: seems to work on my system even with `\:` removed (see revised answer). It seems to redirect all urls that do not match the 7 url patterns you mentioned. If you want the opposite remove the leading `!`. Adding a leading `/` in the pattern (`!^/v/...`) might help in some Apache configurations.